# openPrimaryTab function does not work

Tags: visualforce, consoleintegrationtoolkit

I used the visualforce example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_sample_vf.htm)

This however gives the code:

```
 <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/37.0/integration.js"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function openPrimaryTab() {
            sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(undefined, 
               'http://www.example.com', true, 'example');
        }
```

And then the link should be:

```
<A HREF="#" onClick="openPrimaryTab();return false">Open A Primary Tab</A>
```

Now I would like to have multiple links which open primary tabs. How can you create a general openPrimaryTab() function and then pass in the variables in the onClick function? I tried

```
sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(undefined, url, true, name);
```

And then in the link

```
<A HREF="#" onClick="openPrimaryTab(null,'{!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, Case.Account.Id )}',true,'Account');return false">{!Case.Contact.Name}</a></p>
```

But then the link does not work anymore. How can I set the right variables in order to make this work? Or is the only way to make different functions for every action you want to take? E.g. openAccount, openContact, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you change your signature of openPrimaryTab to take parameters and verify that {!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, Case.Account.Id )} evaluates to a legal URL?

The following code works successfully for me.

```
<apex:page>
<script src="/support/console/37.0/integration.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function openPrimaryTab(v1, v2, v3, v4) {
    sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(v1, v2, v3, v4);
}       
</script>
<A HREF="#" onClick="openPrimaryTab(null,'http://www.example.com',true,'example');return false">Open a primary tab</a>
</apex:page>
```

Or even more simply I can just call the method directly from the anchor tag.

```
<apex:page>
<script src="/support/console/37.0/integration.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<A HREF="#" onClick="sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null,'http://www.example.com',true,'example');return false">Open a primary tab</a>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: That worked! I didn't know I had to add the parameters to the function as well as to sforce.console.openPrimaryTab. Works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Yep, this is the the way it is for javascript and most programming languages as well. If you want to pass parameters to a function, then the function needs to be told how many to expect. This is done by changing what's called the 'function signature'.